# Qt server / Java Client communication problems

Tags: java, c++, qt, sockets

I am currently trying to get a little network communication going between a qt server and a java client.

In my example, the client wants to send an image to the Server. My problem is now, that the server never sees the data, so bytesAvailable() returns 0.

I already tried QDataStream, QTextStream and readAll(), still no data.

Server:

```
QTcpServer* tcpServer;
QTcpSocket* client;
tcpServer = new QTcpServer();

if(!tcpServer->listen(QHostAddress::Any, 7005)){
    tcpServer->close();
    return;
}
... 
tcpServer->waitforNewConnection();
client = tcpServer->nextPendingConnection();
client->waitForConencted();
while(client->state()==connected){
    // Syntax here might be iffy, did it from my phone
    if(client->bytesAvailable()>0){
    //do stuff here, but the program doesnt get here, since bytesAvailable returns 0;
}
```

}

CLient:

```
    public SendPackage() {
    try {
        socket = new Socket(ServerIP, Port);
        socket.setSoTimeout(60000);
        output = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        outwriter = new OutputStreamWriter(output);
    } catch (ConnectException e) {
        System.out.println("Server error, no connection established.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void Send(BufferedImage img) {

    try {

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(img, GUI.imageType, baos);
        baos.flush();
        byte[] imgbyte = baos.toByteArray();
        System.out.println(imgbyte.length);
        System.out.println("sending");

        outwriter.write(imgbyte.length);
        outwriter.flush();
        // here i'd send the image, if i had a connection ...
        output.flush();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The connection and everything builds up fine, the code even tells me when the socket was disconnected when trying to send, so I guess connection isn't a problem.
I just started using Qt, so if you guys have any idea to why this wouldn't work, I'd be pleased to try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
client->waitForConencted();

// At this point the client is connected, but it is likely that no data were received yet

client->waitForReadyRead(-1); // <- Add this

// Now there should be at least 1 byte available, unless waitForConencted or waitForReadyRead failed (you should check that)

if(client->bytesAvailable() > 0) {
    // ...
}
```

Note that you can not expect all the data to arrive at once. The TCP stream can get fragmented in any way and the data will be received in randomly sized pieces. You must repeat waiting and reading until you receive everything. This also means that you must somehow know when you did receive everything. So you need to know how much data is coming, or somehow recognize the end of it. You can for example disconnect right after the data transfer, or send the data length first. Depends on your application.

Also have a look at [QIDevice::readyRead](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#readyRead) signal which would allow you to handle reading asynchronously.

Comment: Actually, im trying to read in a while(connected) loop. I forgot to mention that.

Comment: and the server is running in another thread behind the actual application, so timing is no concern.

Comment: Alright, then you don't need to consider the `QIDevice::readyRead`. But my response is still valid - I think you just try to get the data too soon. Just add `waitForReadyRead` and when it returns you should see some data.

Comment: Thank you! yes, that was my problem :D